# Highcharts: allowDecimals on y-axis when it's logarithmic is ignored

Tags: highcharts, logarithm

I have already made a few hacks (I've made my 0 data to display 0.1, but then hack it back to display as 0; as logarithmic won't allow 0 data) here but my latest question is that when I have a logarithmic y-axis and set allowDecimals to false, it gets ignored I think or might be that my hack is making it that way. To show, here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/index/wXPUx/

The pears chart starts with 0 but then has 0.2 on y-axis. How can I remove/ignore/don't-get-decimals in the y-axis? Basically, I just want to get whole numbers even if it's high.

I hope it's clear. If not, I can provide more or clarify my question more. Or, do you guys have any concerns/ideas how I have/can implement(ed) this?

PS:

The apples chart is to display why I'm using logarithmic y-axis (compare with container2). The small data just get's all the way in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it solves your problem:

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        return (this.value % 1 != 0 ? (this.value != 0.1 ? '' : 0) : this.value);
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/wXPUx/3/)

Comment: Actually this is my temporary fix as well. :) To hide the decimal digits. But I actually want them removed, cause I'm not going to have any decimals anyway ('cept for the hacked 0.1).